# How to create .jpeg osg plugin on windows?

Tags: windows, plugins, jpeg, openscenegraph

I am trying to build *openscenegraph* with *cmake* on windows. At the end it creates **.tga** image plugin but I cant get **.png**, **.tiff** or **.jpeg** plugins.

What are the necessary steps to create those plugins on windows ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The plugins you're interested in are built with the help of 3rd party dependencies. 
You can find prebuilt libraries for Windows on the OpenSceneGraph web site: http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/download-section/32-third-party
To build said plugins update the CMake variable ACTUAL_3RDPRTY_DIR to the folder where you copied the dependency libraries.